# Powershell Active Directory username

Tags: powershell

For a school project, i need to make a Powershell script, but to create a username, with only the first letter of the person name, and the full second name, could anyone help me with this? This is what i currently have:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# password for accounts
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welkom#1" -AsPlainText -Force


# Import the file into a variable
$users = Import-Csv -Path .\New-GaastraUserBulk.csv

# Loop trough each row, and gather Information
ForEach ($user in $users) {

    # Gather the user Information 
    $fname = $user.FirstName
    $lname = $user.LastName
    $jtitle = $user.JobTitle
    $OUpath = $user.OU
    Write-Host $fname
    Write-Host $lname
    Write-Host $jtitle
    Write-Host $OUpath

    #Gebruiker aanmaken in AD 
    New-ADUser -Name "$fname $lname" -GivenName $fname -SamAccountName $lname  -Surname $lname -UserPrincipalName "$lname" -Path $OUpath -AccountPassword $securePassword -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Enabled $true
   
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `"{0}$lname" -f $fname.Substring(0,1)` to use as SamAccountName?. Please, also have a look at [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the multiple parameters for the `New-ADUser` cmdlet. It wil make your code much easier to maintain and a lot easier to read

Comment: hello, i am kinda new to powershell, but rn i got this: New-ADUser -Name "$fname $lname" -GivenName $fname -SamAccountName [string]$Initial = $fname.Substring(0,1) $lname   should that work?

Comment: Hint: for extra credit, also check that there already isn't such samaccountame. For example, `Daan Janssen` and `Dirk Janssen` would both be `djanssen`. This is a common problem in any organization larger than a few users.

Comment: so if a user his name would be Marijn Philippo, id want the SamAccountname to be Mphilippo

Comment: Maybe if someone could edit my script to work like that, it would help alot :D cuz this is my first script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments from others.  Add this line after `$lname = ...`

```
$sam = "{0}$lname" -f $fname.Substring(0,1)
```

Then edit your `New-ADUser` line use `$sam`

```
New-ADUser .... -SamAccountName $sam ...
```

Comment: i currently got this: https://prnt.sc/xyv6bt

I also got a error, but i am completely new... so where do i need to add that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the exact location

Comment: you mean it like this? https://prnt.sc/xyvfnm / With the current script, this it my user output: https://prnt.sc/xyvkvr

Comment: Nope, the `$sam` is an entirely new line after what you had

Comment: i see, but now i get this: https://prnt.sc/xyvu0v

It shows the full first name, but i only wanted the first letter of that, and then the full last name! this is my csv file: https://prnt.sc/xyvwl0 full current script: https://prnt.sc/xyw29n

Comment: But your screen shot is showing the DisplayName which is your `-name` parameter and is not the login name.  Double click the user and check the account tab where it says 'User logon name'

Comment: i see, only it shows the first letter only i think we are very close! https://prnt.sc/xywa29

Now all it does it grab my first name letter, and not the second name!

Comment: Did you leave in your $lname line?  I guess you have have deleted it.  It should be as per your original post and before the $sam line.

Comment: ahh, so what did i do wrong here? https://prnt.sc/xywjv4

Comment: To be clear you need `$fname = $user.FirstName` then `$lname = $user.LastName` then `$sam = "{0}$lname" -f $fname.Substring(0,1)`.

Comment: And `-SamAccountName $sam` on the New-AdUser line

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Then check the New-AdUser line

Comment: thank you so much for your patient man!

I really appreciate it! it now finally works! you mean the world to me!

I am a 16y old student doing it btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer.

You can create the user's SamAccountName quite easily, combining the first character of the users GivenName with the full LastName. However, you need to check that this SamAccountName is not already in use.

Another thing is that the `UserPrincipalName` should be in the form of `<user>@<DNS-domain-name>`.

To improve your code also using Splatting:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# password for accounts
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welkom#1" -AsPlainText -Force

# Import the file into a variable
$users = Import-Csv -Path .\New-GaastraUserBulk.csv

# Loop trough each row, and gather Information
foreach ($user in $users) {
    # first create the desired SamAccountName for the new user
    $accountName = "{0}{1}" -f $user.FirstName.Substring(0,1),$user.LastName 

    # test if a user with that SamAccountName already exists
    $checkUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$accountName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($checkUser) {
        Write-Warning "SamAccountName $accountName already used for user $($checkUser.Name)"
    }
    else {
        # create a hashtable with all parameters for the New-ADUser cmdlet
        $userParams = @{
            Name                 = "$fname $lname"
            GivenName            = $user.FirstName
            Surname              = $user.LastName
            Title                = $user.JobTitle
            SamAccountName       = $accountName
            Path                 = $user.OU
            AccountPassword      = $securePassword
            PasswordNeverExpires = $true
            Enabled              = $true
            UserPrincipalName    = "$accountName@yourdomain.com"  # <-- put YOUR domain here after the '@'
            # other parameters go here if needed
        }

        New-ADUser @userParams
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that you cannot use just any character for a SamAccountName.
Characters `" [ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ , @` are illegal, aswell as non-printable characters and the dot `.` can not be the last character of the name.
AND,  the system limits sAMAccountName to 20 characters for user objects.

To make sure, use something like:

```
$accountName = ($accountName -replace '["\[\]:; |=+\*\?<>/\\,@]').TrimEnd(".") -replace '^(.{1,20}).*', '$1'
```

Comment: @PrayForMarinusX Ah, typo.. I've fixed that now

Comment: @PrayForMarinusX As said.. That is fixed now. It simply needed the final `}` I forgot to copyinto the post the first time. I also changed the variable name of the user to test for clarity to `$checkUser`